# Unable to save key using react-native-secure-key-store

Tags: react-native, android-keystore

When I invoke something like the following to store a key using the `react-native-secure-key-store` package in a React Native project on Android...

```
RNSecureKeyStore.set("my_key", "some-token-123")
.then(res => {
  console.log("Key saved", res);
}, err => {
  console.error("Unable to set key", err);
});
```

...I get an error saying:

> **RNSecureKeyStore.set got 4 arguments, expected 5**

[image: Android error message]

However, looking in the `RNSecureKeyStoreModule.java` file it looks like the `set` method accepts 4 arguments:

```
@ReactMethod
public void set(String alias, String input, @Nullable ReadableMap options, Promise promise)
```

Not really sure what I'm missing here? I've done the usual needle-in-a-haystack things like cleaning and rebuilding the project, removing/reinstalling/re-linking all packages, etc. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `ACCESSIBLE`

**Example**

```js
import RNSecureKeyStore, {ACCESSIBLE} from "react-native-secure-key-store";

// For storing key
RNSecureKeyStore.set("key1", "value1", {accessible: ACCESSIBLE.ALWAYS_THIS_DEVICE_ONLY})
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Wow, you're right - that must have been a breaking change at some point? Didn't realize we had updated to `2.0.4`. :/ Thanks!